# How to Pivot this SQL Table?

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

I run the following T-SQL query

```
SELECT [Path],[Access Scope],[Basic Permissions], STRING_AGG([Display Name], ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [Display Name] ASC) AS Accessors
FROM [dbo].[File_Share_Permissions_Report]
GROUP BY [Path],[Access Scope],[Basic Permissions]
ORDER BY [Path]
```

Which results in a table that looks like this:

```
  Path                       Access Scope                           Basic Permissions       Accessors
\\network\department\path   This folder and subfolders              List folder contents    Dan, Elroy, Kermit
\\network\department\path   This folder, subfolders, and files      Full control            Jimbob, Tails, Mario
\\network\department\path   This folder, subfolders, and files      Modify                  Elly, Waldo, John
```

And I'm trying to modify the query so that the results look like this:

```
Path                        List folder contents -This folder and subfolders    Full control - This folder, subfolders, and files   Modify - This folder, subfolders, and files
\\network\department\path   Dan, Elroy, Kermit                                  Jimbob, Tails, Mario                                Elly, Waldo, John
```

I've been struggling on how to do this - any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation -- a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT [Path], [Access Scope], [Basic Permissions],
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN [Basic Permissions] = 'List folder contents' THEN [Display Name] END,  ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [Display Name] ASC) AS list_Accessors
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN [Basic Permissions] = 'Full control ' THEN [Display Name] END,  ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [Display Name] ASC) AS full_Accessors
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN [Basic Permissions] = 'Modify' THEN [Display Name] END,  ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [Display Name] ASC) AS modify_Accessors
FROM [dbo].[File_Share_Permissions_Report]
GROUP BY [Path],[Access Scope]
ORDER BY [Path]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take the current query as the input table to a pivot query, joining the two cols ([Basic Permissions] and [Access Scope]) into one as the pivot col:

```
select *
from
(
  SELECT [Path],[Access Scope] + ' - ' + [Basic Permissions] PivotOn, STRING_AGG([Display Name], ', ')             WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [Display Name] ASC) AS Accessors
  FROM [dbo].[File_Share_Permissions_Report]
  GROUP BY [Path],[Access Scope],[Basic Permissions]
) pvt
pivot (avg(pvt.Accessors) for pvt.PivotOn in 
        ([This folder and subfolders - List folder contents],
         [This folder, subfolders, and files - Full control],
         [This folder, subfolders, and files - Modify])
) pvted
order by pvted.Path
```